# Something similar to Ext.ux.Livegrid?

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, extjs

Look at this: [www.ext-livegrid.com/demo/](http://www.ext-livegrid.com/demo/)

Is there something like that (scrollable AJAX table) which does not require ExtJS? I'm especially interested in jQuery plugins.